# Javascript/jQuery I can't stop time with setTimeout, error find variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

I use setTimeout to create a time countdown of 5 seconds (it works), but I want to stop the setTimeout with Button Stop, but I have an error finding the variable.

What is the error?

```js
function newTime(ob) {
    
    if(ob==undefined){
        const myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);
        console.log("Start>");
    }
    if(ob=="stop"){
        if(myTimeout==true){
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            console.log("Stop>");
        }
    }
    
}

function myGreeting() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
}

function myStopFunction() {
  newTime("stop");
}
```

```html
<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The setTimeout() and clearTimeout() Methods</h2>

<p>Click "Stop" to prevent myGreeting() to execute. (You have 5 seconds)</p>

<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop!</button>
<button onclick="newTime()">new Time Start</button>

<h2 id="demo"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `const` and `let` variables are block-scoped. In your case, you declared `myTimeout` inside the if block, so the `myTimeout` variable will only be available inside that if block.

To illustrate this better:

#### 1) This will give you a variable not defined error

```
if (true) {
    let foo = 'ok'; 
}
console.log(foo);
```

#### 2) This won't:

```
let foo;
if (true) {
    foo = 'ok'; 
}
console.log(foo);
```

Also, you'll have to declare your variable outside your function, otherwise you won't have access to the value assigned to it on the previous call.

Comment: I always make rookie mistakes. Very sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to move the declaration outside of your newTime function as the scope was limited to just that first call of newTime. Also use let and not const.

```js
let myTimeout;

function newTime(ob) {
    
    if(ob==undefined){
        myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);
        console.log("Start>");
    }
    if(ob=="stop"){
        if(myTimeout==true){
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            console.log("Stop>");
        }
    }
    
}

function myGreeting() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
}

function myStopFunction() {
  newTime("stop");
}
```

```html
<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The setTimeout() and clearTimeout() Methods</h2>

<p>Click "Stop" to prevent myGreeting() to execute. (You have 5 seconds)</p>

<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop!</button>
<button onclick="newTime()">new Time Start</button>

<h2 id="demo"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid the use of inline HTML `on*` JS handler attributes. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead
- Create an Object (singleton) `timer` with the desired properties and methods  like `timer.start(fn)` and `timer.stop()`
- don't forget to assign the timeoutId to a variable (`timer.tOut`) and to clear it when needed.
- Create a `greet` function and pass it

```js
const timer = {
  time: 5000,
  tOut: null,
  stop(callback) {
    callback?.();
    clearTimeout(this.tOut);
    console.log("Stopped");
  },
  start(callback) {
    this.stop(); // Stop ongoing timeout (if there's any)
    this.tOut = setTimeout(callback, this.time);
    console.log("Started!");
  }
};

// Use like:
const elDemo = document.querySelector("#demo");
const elStart = document.querySelector("#timer-start");
const elStop = document.querySelector("#timer-stop");

elStart.addEventListener("click", () => {
  timer.start(() => {
    elDemo.setHTML("Happy birthday!");
  });
});

elStop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  timer.stop(() => {
    elDemo.setHTML("");
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="timer-start">Start New</button>
<button type="button" id="timer-stop">Stop!</button>
<h2 id="demo"></h2>
```

Comment: Your solution is different, but very clear. Thank you.

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma a bit, yes. You're very welcome.